# How to hide keyboard automatically in sony xperia using android code?

Tags: android, soft-keyboard

I am using `Textview` and `ImageView` display for some things in my layout,I did not

use any `EditView` in my latout. But whenever I run my application in sony xperia device, I

got keyboard view, How can i hide keyboard, This problem only appear in sony xperia, How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Where is your layout? and possibly some code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"` for your activity in maifest file.